# javaScript Resources are not shown in Project Expolorer in sts

Tags: javascript, spring-mvc, sts

To make my project I first go *new select maven project web Archetype* and press OK, but every folder I have got the rest of JavaScript Resources.
I have added every plugin depency install eclipse JavaScript from Eclipse marketplace

[image]

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please visit the [help], take the [tour] to see what and [ask]. Do some research.  If you get stuck, post a [mcve] of your attempt, noting input and expected output using the [\[<>\]](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/358992/ive-been-told-to-create-a-runnable-example-with-stack-snippets-how-do-i-do) snippet editor.

Comment: Please take more care in spelling and describing your issues. I tried to clean up your text. Use Google Translate if necessary. It is really hard to understand the issue